# Obtaining a request attribute in an OpenAPI-generated controller in Micronaut

Tags: java, openapi, micronaut

I've generated a controller in Micronaut from an OpenAPI spec, but it's missing a way to access to the attributes in the request object. Consider the following OpenAPI spec:

```yaml
...
paths:
  /api/auth/login:
    post:
      tags:
        - auth
      summary: User login
      operationId: login
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginRequest'
...
```

The generated controller method looks like the following

```java
@Post("/api/auth/login")
@Produces({})
@Consumes({"application/json"})
HttpResponse<Void> login(
    @Body
    LoginRequest loginRequest
);
```

Is there a way to obtain the request object in order to have access to the attributes set by a filter?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `ServerRequestContext.currentRequest()` to obtain the current request.

```java
var req = ServerRequestContext.currentRequest().orElseThrow();
var requestAttr = req.getAttribute("myattr").orElseThrow();
```